# Automatically identify obsolete variables in init-file

Tags: init-file

When a new version of Emacs is released it is usually the case that some variables/commands/functions become obsolete. They are usually marked as such in the corresponding documentation:

> `turn-on-eldoc-mode` is an alias for `eldoc-mode` in `eldoc.el`. [...]
>
> **This function is obsolete since 24.4**; use `eldoc-mode` instead.

I'd like to make sure I am not referencing any obsolete variables in my init-file, but I'd also like to avoid checking the whole thing manually.

**So my question is**: Is there a way to automatically identify all obsolete variables in my init-file (that possibly also works for third-party packages installed via the package manager)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Byte-compile the file.**

Generally, it's best to not byte-compile your init file, but here it's useful. The byte-compiler will warn you about a lot of bad practices, among them is the usage of obsolete variables or functions.

1. Just call `M-x` `byte-compile-file` and give your init file.
2. Afterwards, make sure you delete the generated `.elc` file.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the reasons not to byte-compile the init file?

Comment: @Dan The advantages are negligible.  Meanwhile, occasionally you might forget to recompile after changing it, and be left wondering why your changes aren't having any effect.

Comment: @Dan: In addition to what Malabarba said, a given init file is sometimes (often) used for multiple Emacs versions, and byte-compiling it can reduce this kind of portability.

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious: you can byte-compile it (to see warnings etc.) and then delete the `*.elc`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I don't really get the behavior you describe. For instance, if I put `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'turn-on-eldoc-mode)` into my init-file and compile it, the byte compiler should warn me that `turn-on-eldoc-mode` is obsolete. At least that's what I would expect based on the docstring. But I get no such warning. I tried to byte-compile the file with and without my customizations loaded; results were the same (w/r/t obsolete variables).

Comment: That's why you should use `#'` instead of `'` for functions. If you compile something with `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'turn-on-eldoc-mode)` the compiler will warn you.